# How would I pass an unnamed (new) array as an argument c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Instead of doing something like

```
char attach_bytes[4];
attach_bytes[0] = 1;
attach_bytes[1] = 2;
attach_bytes[2] = 3;
attach_bytes[3] = 4;
FindPattern(0, 0, attach_bytes, 0);
```

I want would like to do something like

```
FindPattern(0, 0, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], 0);
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: depending on your compiler `FindPattern(0, 0, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 0);`

Comment: @DanielSanchez I get the error "too many initializer values"

Comment: actually is not working, you would have to use array class itself